# Impala SQL - Get Maximum Time Stamp Records - Not Yielding Results

Tags: sql, impala

I have the below table where i need to get the records with latest timestamp across each source and table.
The timestamp is in Unix format with 1531204200 being the latest timestamp.

The data on the table is as below:

```
src_sys_id  st_mgmnt_cd tblnm               execn_ts    rcd_cnt
SOURCE1     HOT         SUBSCRBR_ACCT_HIST  1531204200  28680
SOURCE1     COLD        SUBSCRBR_ACCT_HIST  1531204200  11874
SOURCE1     WARM        MEMBR_HIST          1531204200  13698
SOURCE1     WARM        SUBSCRBR_ACCT_HIST  1531204200  24211
SOURCE1     HOT         MEMBR_HIST          1531204200  18500
SOURCE2     FINAL       CLAIM               1531204200  5000
SOURCE2     EXPIRED     CLAIM               1531204200  8000
SOURCE2     WARM        CLAIM               1531204200  20000
SOURCE2     HOT         CLAIM               1531204200  45000
SOURCE2     COLD        CLAIM               1531204200  10000
SOURCE3     WARM        INDIV_CVRG          1531204200  2763
SOURCE3     HOT         INDIV_CVRG          1531204200  11874
SOURCE1     HOT         MEMBR_HIST          1528650875  32198
SOURCE2     WARM        CLAIM               1528650875  28000
SOURCE2     HOT         CLAIM               1528650875  60000
SOURCE3     HOT         INDIV_CVRG          1528650875  14637
```

The expect output is as below:

```
src_sys_id  st_mgmnt_cd tblnm               execn_ts    rcd_cnt
SOURCE1     HOT         SUBSCRBR_ACCT_HIST  1531204200  28680
SOURCE1     COLD        SUBSCRBR_ACCT_HIST  1531204200  11874
SOURCE1     WARM        MEMBR_HIST          1531204200  13698
SOURCE1     WARM        SUBSCRBR_ACCT_HIST  1531204200  24211
SOURCE1     HOT         MEMBR_HIST          1531204200  18500
SOURCE2     FINAL       CLAIM               1531204200  5000
SOURCE2     EXPIRED     CLAIM               1531204200  8000
SOURCE2     WARM        CLAIM               1531204200  20000
SOURCE2     HOT         CLAIM               1531204200  45000
SOURCE2     COLD        CLAIM               1531204200  10000
SOURCE3     WARM        INDIV_CVRG          1531204200  2763
SOURCE3     HOT         INDIV_CVRG          1531204200  11874
```

I used below query

```
   Select distinct s1.src_sys_id ,
          s1.st_mgmnt_cd,
          from_unixtime(CAST(s2.execn_ts AS BIGINT)) as assessment_dt,
          s1.rcd_cnt
          from dlrm_data_retention.ret_st_mgmnt_sum s1           
          INNER JOIN
          ( select src_sys_id,st_mgmnt_cd,rcd_cnt,execn_ts,row_number() over (partition by src_sys_id order by execn_ts desc) as seqnum
                from dlrm_data_retention.ret_st_mgmnt_sum
           ) s2
           on s1.src_sys_id = s2.src_sys_id and s2.seqnum = 1
```

This is not yielding the results. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of ROW_NUMBER plus OVER (PARTITION BY + ORDER BY):

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                   PARTITION BY table.src_sys_id,
                                table.st_mgmnt_cd
                   ORDER BY table.execn_ts DESC) AS row_number
         FROM table) as time_sorted
    WHERE row_number = 1

    ) as recent
    WHERE row_number=1;
```

You first SubSelect the desired Partitions(aka. GROUPS) and ORDER them - in your case by the timestamp. The Row_Number goes from 1..n for each group.

The desired results all have row_number=1.

Please refer to https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html#over for more information on the Impala-OVER Syntax.